# Are individual words really constituents?

Tags: syntax, terminology, phrase-structure, constituents

The constituent unit is defined in Wikipedia as *a word or a group of words that functions as a single unit within a hierarchical structure*. When phrase structure trees are produced, each node in the tree marks a constituent. Thus, each individual word is a constituent in phrase structure grammars just by virtue of being a word.

There is a major problem in this area. The tests for identifying constituents employed in the same phrase structure grammars contradict this starting assumption concerning individual words as constituents. Most individual words fail the majority of tests for identifying constituents that are employed in syntax and grammar textbooks (e.g. topicalization, clefting, pseudoclefting, answer fragments, proform substitution, etc.). A bit of time spent reading the [Wikipedia article on the constituent unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)) makes this point clear. That article discusses the constituent structure of the sentence *Drunks could put off the customers*. Of the six words present in the sentence, only one of them, i.e. the subject nominal *Drunks*, passes most of the tests. The other five fail most of the tests. The next data set and those further below are taken from the Wikipedia article; they illustrate that the other five individual words do not behave as constituents with respect to the tests. The first examples are of topicalization:

[image]

The same five words fail the clefting test:

[image]

They also fail the answer fragment test:

[image]

They also fail the proform substitution test:

[image]

Similar results obtain for the majority of tests for constituents discussed in the article (15 of them altogether). Only one of the tests, i.e. coordination, regularly suggests that individual words are constituents. The point, then, is that many tests for constituents actually suggest that most individual words are in fact NOT constituents.

The next questions derive from this insight. Isn't this a problem for phrase structure grammars, and if it is not a problem, why is it not a problem? Should the term *tests for constituents* be renamed to something else, perhaps to *tests for phrases*, since many (but certainly not all!) phrases pass most of the tests? I of course have a concrete opinion about all this, but I am respectfully requesting that the phrase structure people here share their views and understanding.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109388/discussion-on-question-by-tim-osborne-are-individual-words-really-constituents).

Comment: Reaction to your edit: You can’t conclude ¬A⊃¬B from A⊃B, only the contrapositive. This is actually an interesting question, are there negative constituency tests?

Comment: @Atamiri, Please note the wording, that is, the use of the verb "suggest". Yes, it is an interesting question and an important one. It goes to the heart of dependency vs. phrase structure distinction.

Comment: Yes, I see the verb “suggest”, but tests for constituency are material implications, they only suggest something if true. If a test comes out as false it doesn’t suggest anything. In particular, if one out of ten tests can be applied, it follows that the tested phrase IS a constituent.

Comment: @Atamiri, No. That reasoning would allow most any string to count as a constituent; it's too permissive. Consider the flexibility of coordination in this regard. Read Section 7.1 in the article: https://journals.helsinki.fi/lud/article/view/223/173.

Comment: This is how constituency tests work, they aren’t bijections. This is trivial propositional logic, very simple and clear. See the first two sentences here: https://tildeweb.au.dk/au572/Teaching/krc-syn_constituency.pdf In any case, every (PP) linguist has a feel for what a constituent is, there are no controversies. Doubts can be easily resolved by writing down the rules formally and verifying that they correctly model the phrase at hand. My students never have problems identifying constituents.

Comment: @Atamiri You have not addressed my point and your further statements are a diversion. Here's a concrete case: _[Fred has], but [Susan hasn't], understood the point_. By your reasoning, _Fred has_ is a constituent because it passes the coordination test. Most phrase structure people do not view _Fred has_ as a constituent.

Comment: @Atamiri, Interestingly, the examples in the document you have linked to support my message. Most of the test strings that are positively identified as constituents are phrases. The tests are not applied to individual words. Try it though. Apply the tests listed and illustrated in the document to individual words!

Comment: @Atamiri is the conjunction test a negative constituency test?

Comment: It doesn't look to me as though you're going to get any further answers and I can't see the people I think you have in mind being motivated by a bounty. I hope you'll answer your own question anyway. I have not really grasped what is supposed to turn on this issue and suspect you are reifying constituents too much - I think it's more a question of what role constituency can / should play in a theory and how well different conceptions of it fit that role. At the moment you have no job description for constituency but are still asking for an appraisal.

Comment: @rchivers I don't think so and I'm not sure there are any conclusive negative tests for constituency. If a test fails, it's basically "absence of evidence".

Comment: @Atamiri You may well be right, idk - what examples are there of constituents that fail the coordination test?

Comment: @rchivers I may answer the question as you suggest, or I may not. I have not yet decided. If I do decide to answer, I will point out that on a dependency grammar approach to constituent structure, most individual words are predicted to fail the tests for constituents. This point is established at length in the articles that have been bounced around in the comments.

Comment: @rchivers Why don't you answer the question along the lines of your comment. You might simply point out that you do not understand the point of the question and that you think too much emphasis is being placed on the constituent notion. That could open the door to more insightful discussion, and I would be grateful for your answer.

Comment: Well, because that's exactly what comments are for, and it wouldn't amount to an answer to your question. In all honesty I have no answer, which is why I'm interested to see yours.

Comment: @rchivers, OK, I do hope, though, that someone has the courage to produce an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I only wanted to write a comment but I’d like to include a tree so here’s a more detailed answer. First of all, constituents are defined by context-free rules, not by tests. The tests can be used to devise the rules but they’re defeasible implications. Even if they were material implications, if one is true, the converse needn’t be. But this is elementary.

Consider the Eastern Armenian sentence *Ես Երևան եմ գնում* “I go to Yerevan.” Its syntax tree is

[image]

This is completely uncontroversial, there’s no alternative sensible way of parsing the sentence. The point here is that the enclitic auxiliary is a pragmatic marker and moving the NP *Yerevan* around the sentence drags the auxiliary with it (since it needs to remain focus marked). So *Yerevan* is the categorial head of the auxiliary, but at the same time the auxiliary is the dependency head of *Yerevan* — by virtue of being a cohead together with the main verb but this isn’t germane here. The point is, it doesn’t make sense to apply constituency tests to single words (in the sentence at hand the auxiliary could be dispensed with if the verb were in future tense) and the obvious (but apparently still worth pointing out) point is that a true implication doesn’t make its converse true.

I’ve digressed a bit — the short answer is that individual words (more precisely their preterminals) are constituents by definition.

**Edit:** A similar example would be “Robert goes to Yerevan” with the subject in focus, i.e., with the auxiliary farther away from the main verb. The auxiliary is the verb “to be” which can also serve as a copula.

[image]

Comment: For this answer to start to be coherent, the example from Armeninan would need a three-level gloss (romanization, element-for-element translation with morphological information, and English meaning). As it is, it is only comprehensible to those who know Armenian. Linguistic reasoning that is based on impenetrable examples requires faith, which has no place in science.

Comment: @TimOsborne Can't you see the tree with the romanised transcription?

Comment: Yes, I saw those. But I see you claiming that _em_ receives the gloss _I_. What is that? Inflection? Does that mean that _em_ is agreeing with a lingusitically absent subject pronoun? Or is _yes_ the subject pronoun? What does NP with subscript p mean? Des the p stand for particle? It if does, then _em_ is actually not an auxiliary verb.The failure to provide the standard three-level gloss means that the reader  is unable to interpret your example in these areas.

Comment: @TimOsborne Yes, the auxiliary must agree with the subject, dropped or not. But the point here is the distinction between what linguists call “categorial” and “functional” heads, which you consistently overlook. The tree alone is a clear illustration of what’s going an, as there’s an apparent dependency cycle, and a particularly clear counterexample to (one aspect of) your trees.

Comment: So _yes_ is the subject pronoun, right? Just to be sure, the form of the clitic changes if the subject changes. If the sentence were, say, 'You go to Yerevan', the clitic _em_ would have a different form. Is that right? If possible, you could produce a similar example from a language closer to home? Can you illustrate the point with an example form English or German or some other related language? English also has clitic auxiliaries. It'd be good to see your point illustrated with an English example.

Comment: By the way, I am not the one who voted your answer down.

Comment: @TimOsborne Yes, it’s the subject pronoun and it agrees with the auxiliary. I should have used a given name as the subject of the sentence but it can also be dropped if the antecedent isn’t contrastive or focussed. This peculiar syntactic construction is typical of the language area of the South Caucasus. Generally this sort of discontinuity is dealt with by an exocentric rule which makes the distinction less clear cut. I can’t think of any structurally identical example from German or Spanish. There’s something very similar in Silesian (and archaic Polish) but I don’t think that helps.

Comment: The form of _em_ definitely changes as the subject changes? What would the sentence be if the subject is 'you'? My suspicion at present is that _em_ is in fact NOT an auxiliary verb, but rather a particle. Why would an auxiliary verb that agrees with the subject be attaching as a clitic to an oblique object? If it were a 2nd position clitic, it would be less enigmatic.

Comment: @TimOsborne Yes, it changes, it’s a conjugated auxiliary verb. It can attach to any NP regardless of its GF or to an adverb, as it always attaches to the focussed phrase. Yes, it’s “enigmatic”, that’s why it’s a very interesting example. In Silesian the situation is even more involved — the enclosing auxiliary attaches to a particle which is always in second position, so the parse tree is structurally identical to the Armenian one but the phrase with the auxiliary can’t be moved around the sentence.

Comment: Let me assume that your description of the Armenian example is accurate. My DG analysis of the example would position the clitic _em_ as the root of the sentence, similar to the analysis I prefer in English for the  clitic _'s_ in a sentence such as _Frank's sleeping_. On this approach, the sentence is entirely endocentric.

Comment: @TimOsborne Of course it’s accurate, I’m only providing data. The point is that in this construction the categorial head of the pragmatically marked NP is the noun. You don’t distinguish between categorial and functional heads so here you contradict yourself. I’m adding one more example which is very similar but the auxiliary isn’t adjacent to the main verb.

Comment: I now understand your point, finally. But you are sure that my solution is not plausible? What is preventing the analysis from viewing the clitic as the syntactic root of these sentences similar to the auxiliary clitic _'s_ in English being the root of a sentence such as _Frank's sleeping_? In other words, there are other potential analyses of the Armenian sentences in your answer.

Comment: @TimOsborne Your tree doesn’t account for the fact that the auxiliary and the pragmatically marked noun form a constituent and must me moved together around the sentence. Your approach is somewhat similar to that of Oliva from Saarbrücken (his DG analyses of free word order phenomena also use categorial heads to some extent) but his way of converting phrase structure trees into dependency trees is consistent in that he respects categorial heads without exceptions.

Comment: I am not confident about my suggested analysis, nor am I about yours. The main problem is that you are building an argument based on examples from a language that I do not know at all. I also assume you do not know Armenian. I am therefore not confident that the facts of Armenian are being described accurately. All I have to go on at present is one linguist's claims. That Wikipedia article on Armenian verbs does not provide any guidance concerning the phenomenon you point to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_verbs#Present_2.

Comment: @TimOsborne I do speak Armenian but it’s not my native language. I discussed this issue (word order and pragmatic marking) with native Armenian speakers — both linguists and non-linguists. It’s nothing new, there was a PhD thesis on this type of construction in 1994 at UCL (Tamrazian). I just elicited more examples from Armenians, the interpretation isn’t mine. (I’ll edit my answer now to emphasise that all analyses refer to Eastern Armenian, in Western Armenian the auxiliary behaves differently).

Comment: Great. I also recommend that you expand your answer so that it more directly addresses the key issue. This issue is that phrase structure grammars understand every node in the tree to mark a constituent, whereas there may not be evidence supporting the existence of so many constituents. I can again point to this article if you would like to see what is motivating the question in the first place: https://journals.helsinki.fi/lud/article/view/223.

Comment: @TimOsborne I saw the article some time ago and also the responses to it including Müller’s scathing critique of your approach.

Comment: Did you see my response to Mueller?

Comment: Here's my full response to all the discussion notes: https://journals.helsinki.fi/lud/article/view/228

Comment: @TimOsborne I reread the polemic. I agree with Müller that you need to formalise and augment your approach since at this point it’s “not even wrong.” If you want theoretical linguists to take it seriously, you need to explain why you prefer categorial heads over functional heads (most DGs use exclusively functional heads) and as a minimum you need to have a system of formalisable rules. This would — as a by-product — sort out the inconsistencies the Armenian example revealed. If you want I can help you with the formalisable rules, it’d be worth fixing up.

Comment: I am very interested to learn what you have in mind. Please contact me via email: tjo3ya@yahoo.com.

Comment: @TimOsborne As I said, you need to add completely formal rules that produce your trees (you can have auxiliaries where you want provided you clearly state that you model categorial heads, not functional heads, in order not to confuse DG people with established theories). These rules need to be fully formalised and accept all and only well-formed sentences. You may also consider linking the nodes of your trees in a principles way to argument structures (like those of O’Grady). I’d prefer you ask here (e.g. “how to add rules to a DG approach”) so others can learn how rules are devised.

Comment: Prefer to remain anonymous, huh? In any case, I have posted the question. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @TimOsborne I prefer others can follow the process (and comment on it), it can be instructive. If you like the final result we can then author a paper together if you wish ;) My goal is to make theoretical syntacticians like it.

Comment: I am very interested to see what you provide.

Comment: @TimOsborne I have one question — can you read papers written in French? Just so I know whether it makes sense to recommend some to you. And please be patient, it may take some time to produce a sufficiently detailed answer.

Comment: Yes, I can read French, but it certainly takes more time and effort for me. I would also caution that the answer need not be too detailed, for it might overwhelm me and other readers.